# how to know when a url is loaded using fopen in php?

Tags: php, fopen

I'm calling fopen like this: `fopen($url.urlencode("\"-BENCHMARK(100000000, rand()) -- -"),"r");`

But i don't know when the return of the function appends. (i tried to put an echo just after and it executes immediatly...maybe fopen create a subthreads..), any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"how to know when a url is loaded using fopen in php?"* -- most probably, [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns as soon as the first data packet of the response is received. You have to [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) (or similar) from the resource returned by `fopen()` until [`feof()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php) returns `TRUE` to find out when the response is complete.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP documentation:

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

Comment: Ok, so i don't understand. If i put an echo "something" just after fopen() in my code, why does the "something" displayed direclty (no time delay at all) ?

Comment: By the time you get to see "something", your `fopen` function is executed. It all happens when loading your webpage. You might want to learn about the basics of PHP first.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (!$handle = fopen($url.urlencode("\"-BENCHMARK(100000000, rand()) ---"),"r"))
{
    echo "error";
} else {
   //do something with $handle
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you checked the log to see the output? Maybe you're entering a invalid argument as a URL